# Cannot read property 'applicationDirectory in cordova

Tags: javascript, file, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am working on a Cordova application.

When I run the application for first time after installation, it works fine. But for subsequent runs it throws above error.

> Added the cordova file transfer plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
```

> Included the cordova script in my index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Using the app directory as below

```
alert(cordova.file.applicationDirectory);
```

> Above line alerts or prints the path correctly when I run my application for the first time, soon after installation. But in the next runs I get the error "Cannot read property 'applicationDirectory' of undefined".

> **ANSWER IN BELOW COMMENTS**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My issue fixed when I used the "file:///android_asset/www/Images/" instead of `cordova.file.applicationDirectory+"/Images"`